# 32-bit depth buffer in OpenTK GLControl

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk, depth-buffer

How to set a number of bits in the depth buffer of GLControl? I've tried this:

```cs
GLControl glControl = new GLControl(
    new GraphicsMode( new ColorFormat(8,8,8,8), 32));
```

and it still gives 24-bit depth buffer.

What am I missing?

Comment: Chances are that your graphics card does not support 32-bit depth buffers.

Answer (score 1):

Your GPU most likely supports 32bit depth, but not when rendering to the default framebuffer. To obtain a 32bit depth buffer you need to create and render to a framebuffer object. Refer to the following page in the OpenTK documentation: http://www.opentk.com/doc/graphics/frame-buffer-objects

Unlike the default framebuffer, which may expose different capabilities depending on the driver and operating system, framebuffer objects give you complete control over the pixel format.